# Selecting a transceiver module for a wireless communication system

Tags: pic, wireless, communication, transceiver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestions for a Point-to-Point reliable Wireless Communication Module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38154/suggestions-for-a-point-to-point-reliable-wireless-communication-module)

I got a project to design a wireless communication system in order to communicate between the factory and the factory's pump station which is situated about 600m away from the factory. In between the two end stations there's an estate with no any buildings, there are planted coconut trees. But, no line of sight is present between two end stations.

I need to start this soon. As I don't have any prior experiences in using wireless communication designs for my projects, I came here to ask for guidance from the experts..

I have one major question here.

```
What is the suitable transceiver module that can be used here?
```

I searched a lot, but couldn't figure out a proper one.

Please consider that I'm hoping to use PIC micro-controllers to handle the modules (can go for Arduino, if needed)..

Any thought, advice is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What data throughput do you need? Is power supply an issue?

Comment: i won't need a higher throughput. No issue with the power supply..

Comment: What's "not higher"? is that 9600 bps, 250 kbps?

Comment: @stevenvh actually the system will be used to control the pumps at the pump station, and there are less than 10 pumps there..

Comment: @stevenvh sorry I'm not experienced enough to convert the requirement into an expected throughput. May be you'll help me with that too. thanks..

Answer (score 5):

Digi's [Xbee modules](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/zigbee-mesh-module/xbee-zb-module#overview) may be interesting. The XBee PRO ZB has a maximum range of 3.2 km, and the modules have a completely transparent Zigbee protocol implementation. Means that you use the module as a simple UART connection.

You want to control the pumps with this, so I'm thinking **reliability**! Pumps should not be switched off or on by others on the network, and if you send a command to switch pump 4 on it has to be switched on for sure.

That's what your software should take care off. I would suggest some kind of encryption, and include error correction. Let the pump station acknowledge a command, and include commands for asking a pump's state.

Comment: yeah I completely agree with your suggestions on reliability. Of course that will be a major issue if not seriously taken. BTW, what is the frequency range that this module is operating? Is it free band? I mean, will it be needed to get some special permission to use it?

Comment: @Anubis - Most operate in the 2.4 GHz ISM band (Industrial, Scientific, Medical). This is regulated, but you don't need a license. I'm not sure about what the regulations include, but it's probably duty cycle and power.

Comment: Well, the thing seems to bit a costly.. does that this worth that much? I saw RF modules, with less range (around 500m) for amounts less than $200. why do you select Xbee anyway?

Comment: About your previous(first) comment, yeah that what I asked, whether it operate in ISM band (free band). (Don't need to know about the regulation content..) Thanks..

Comment: $100? Digikey has Xbee modules for less than 20 dollar. For professional use 40 dollar shouldn't be a hurdle. 500 m range is no good. That's maximum, so you're lucky if you get 600 m with it, especially since you don't have LoS (Line of Sight). I thought about the Xbee because I knew they have high power versions for several km range.

Comment: Excuse me for that, but your link pointed me to a $299 Xbee kit.

Comment: [XBee® / RF Family Features Comparison](http://www.digi.com/pdf/chart_xbee_rf_features.pdf)

Comment: @Anubis - Yes, the link is on that page *as well*, but I didn't want to sell you that :-). I've never understood why these kits have to be so expensive, anyway.

Comment: yeah I understand, sorry if I'm bothering. I'll highlight again I'm not experienced in wireless apps. It would be **much** appreciated if you can point me to a proper module **directly** (without letting me to make harder decisions), then I'll consider about that. Budget will not be an issue, as the company'll pay, but I think cost of the above device is way too high (i'll require two of them, eh?). I need to do this somehow. It'll be a valuable experience for me. So please be kind enough to give your valuable guidance, I'll be much thankful..